# Вывод чисел в псевдофайл

Tags: c, linux

Помогите с вопросом по модулю ядра!

В общем нужно выводить числа рандомные не в журнал ядра, а записывать в псевдофайл, чтобы потом оттуда можно было считать (к примеру написав `cat /proc/mybuffer`).

Answer (score 1):

Может, эта ссылка поможет: [файловая система /proc: создание файлов, доступных для чтения](http://www.linuxcenter.ru/lib/books/lkmpg.phtml#THEPROCFILESYSTEMFORREAD).

Comment: ссылка очень хорошая! Но вот тут не совсем есть то что мне нужно, либо я этого не вижу(

Comment: Это классическое руководство по созданию модулей ядра. Посмотрите там все от начала до конца